# The program can't start because MSVCR110.dll is missing from your computer

Tags: apache, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, webserver

I'm trying to install apache server 2.4 onto my (windows) computer and so far I've run in to this "common" problem but I cannot resolve it. The error message in the title continues to come up, but I have downloaded both the 32 and 64 bit version (successfully) of the missing required item from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679#. When I search for 'msvcr110.dll' in windows explorer, I can see a couple files of that name so I'm wondering why apache can't locate it. I have tried to find the solution online, but each one points directly to the resource I've mentioned previously in this post. If anyone can add any insight it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you put them in the correct folders? The msvcr files, I mean.

Answer (score 32):

You need to install the Visual C++ libraries: 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Comment: This worked for me, when I chose proper version of the pack (32/64 bit) :)

Answer (score 14):

I would like to quote an answer given by Microsoft support engineer at here:-

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-winapps/the-program-cant-start-because-msvcr110dll-is/f052d325-3af9-4ae5-990b-b080799724db

> Hi Henny,   MSVCR110.dll is the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable
>   dll that is needed for projects built with Visual Studio 2011. The dll
>   letters spell this out. MS = Microsoft, V = Visual, C = C++, R =
>   Redistributable For Winroy to get started, this file is probably
>   needed. This error appears when you wish to run a software which
>   require the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2012. The
>   redistributable can easily be downloaded on the Microsoft website as
>   x86 or x64 edition. Depending on the software you wish to install you
>   need to install either the 32 bit or the 64 bit version. Refer the
>   following link:
>   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679#
>       Please let us know if the issue persists. We will be happy to assist you further. Thanks, Yaqub Khan - Microsoft Support Engineer

Comment: Notice that for Apache x64, you need Visual C++ x64 package and for Apache x86 you need Visual c++ x86

Answer (score 1):

You can download the required files from the Microsoft website or online or reinstall the Visual studio 2012  to fix this.

Comment: True. Look for file VSU_4\vcredist_x86.exe and it should work again.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a similar issue from the Apache Lounge 32 bit version. After downloading the 64 bit version, the issue was resolved.

Here is an excellent video explain the steps involved:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=17qhikHv5hY

Answer (score 1):

This error appears when you wish to run a software which require the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2012. Download it fromMicrosoft website as x86 or x64 edition. Depending on the software you wish to install you need to install either the 32 bit or the 64 bit version. Visit the following link:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679#

Answer (score 0):

Weird, just had simmilar issue, went here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30679 downloaded and installed vcredist_x86 (i'm using 32bit apache) and it works like a charm.