# PHP is not running on IIS Windows Server 2012 although FastCGI is and MySQL is

Tags: php, dll, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2, syswow64

I have Windows Server 2012 R2 and have PHP Manager installed on IIS8.

I try to hit the simple "localhost/phpinfo.php" and I get the following:

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Most likely causes:
The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server.
The URL contains a typographical error.
A custom filter or module, such as URLScan, restricts access to the file.

Things you can try:
Create the content on the Web server.
Review the browser URL.
Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code and see which module is calling SetStatus. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click here.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       MapRequestHandler
Handler    PHP56_via_FastCGI
Error Code     0x80070002
Requested URL      http://localhost:80/phpinfo.php
Physical Path      D:\inetpub\wwwroot\ccretebase\phpinfo.php
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous
```

So I looked up the errorcode and to no avail, there's nothing that applies to my situation.

[http://forums.iis.net/t/1166213.aspx?The+FastCGI+executable+Error+Number+2+0x80070002+](http://forums.iis.net/t/1166213.aspx?The%20FastCGI%20executable%20Error%20Number%202%200x80070002%20)

I have installed the CORRECT version of MSVCR110.dll via *vcredist_x86.exe* after I tried *vcredist_x64.exe*.

[The program can't start because MSVCR110.dll is missing from your computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20924363/the-program-cant-start-because-msvcr110-dll-is-missing-from-your-computer)

I have ensured that the DLL is in both the `System32` and `SYSWOW64` folders.

Still, PHP is not running under IIS8 as it's supposed to.

I simply want to run Concrete5.  I was able to do it before on another Win2012 server but I forgot how and that server is gone.... needed to COPY the procedure docs.... Dummy me!

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated...

**UPDATE:** While trying to HIT my server from my local machine or from internal to the server; I get this now:

```
**HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.6\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly**
```

UPDATE 2: Marc's question:  This is what I get:

```
Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       MapRequestHandler
Handler    PHP56_via_FastCGI
Error Code     0x80070002
Requested URL      http://localhost:80/ccretebase/phpinfo.php
Physical Path      D:\inetpub\wwwroot\ccretebase\ccretebase\phpinfo.php
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous
```

ALSO: Here is the *Basic Settings* dialog:

[image]

OF NOTE: `D:\inetpub\wwwroot` is registered with IIS as the `D:` drive on my server has just over 800GB and the `C:` Drive just under 25GB left... 1and1 doesn't partition the drives as I need.  Need to get Aome for Servers to move space from `D:` to `C:`, unless anyone has a "FREE" open source way...

MARC UPDATE!!! Marc, Thanks and I checked and reinstalled them. Both in the "correct" folders... 32-bits in `SYSWOW64` and 64-bits in `System32`... yeah, a little weird.

I tested the file again and ...........WALA!!!! FRIGGIN' EH!!!! YOU DA MAN!!!! AWESOME DUDE!

Have a look, sir!!!! Woo Hoo!!!

[image]

Comment: What happens if you try to access the following URL: `localhost/ccretebase/phpinfo.php` ?

Comment: See NOTE inside question under UPDATE 2: Marc. Thanks...

Comment: Do you have exactly the same DLL file under both `system32` and `SysWOW64` folders? (hint: check its size in bytes)

Comment: Marc, yes, just verified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said in the comments that the size of the msvcr100.dll file is the same under both the `System32` and `SysWOW64` folders.

There's your problem. The `System32` folder should contain the 64-bit DLL, and the `SysWOW64` folder should contain the 32-bit DLL (yes, a bit confusing maybe). They tipically differ on size; On my system (Windows 10), they are 809KB and 755KB, respectively. I suggest re-installing both Visual C++ packages.